# Can I create a stream from macro camera when available?

Tags: javascript, webrtc, getusermedia, mediadevices, enumerate-devices

Is there any way to get a stream of the macro camera using the `mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints)`?

I'm trying to create a web app that will scan printed out barcodes and noticed that on some phones like Samsung A51, if I just use the `facingMode: environment` as a constraint, it opens the default camera which cannot focus on very small distances and as a result I have to change camera  (I get them via `enumerateDevices()`)and test again till I find the proper one (macro).

So, I was thinking of applying some more specific constraints to fetch the macro camera at first try, but I am not sure what exactly constraints to apply.

Comment: I have a little diagnostic web app that grabs a lot of getUserMedia constraint / characteristic / setting stuff from a mobile phone (or computer) browser. https://lit-mesa-75588.herokuapp.com/  It's not slick; it shows its output in JSON. Give it a try. You may see a constraint you can use. (The desktop version shows a QR code so you don't have to type the URL into your mobile device.)

Comment: Hi @O.Jones, I am planning to make a simple utility web app just for getting cameras and I think this does a similar job but better. I checked your GitHub repo just in case you already shared it but I wasn't able to find it. If it's alright, would you mind sharing the code for this? Thanks.